# Addition of select or dropdown menu with options inside PHP $output

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I want to make a dropdown menu in PHP. Now when I select a dropdown menu and submit it in my database the entire text that is: "Open this select menu
 One
 Two
 Three" appears, but I only want the text which I select from the dropdown menu to appear.

PHP:

```php
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows > 0) {  
     if($rows > 10) {
         $delete_records = $rows - 10;
         $delete_sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_sample LIMIT $delete_records";
         mysqli_query($connect, $delete_sql);
     }
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {      
          $output .= '  
               <tr>  

                    <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>  
                    <td class="last_name" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>  
                    <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
               </tr>  
          ';  
     }  

//Main code here...  //
  $output .= '  
          <tr>  

               <td id="first_name" contenteditable>
<select class="custom-select" multiple>
 <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
  </td>  
               <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
               <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
          </tr>  
     ';  
} else {  
     $output .= '
               <tr>  

                   <td id="first_name" contenteditable></td>  
                   <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
                   <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
              </tr>';  
}  
$output .= '</table> 
     </div>';  
echo $output;  
?>
```

Comment: Hi there. Your question isn't very clear. Seems there is more code required. Is the error in the database, PHP, html?

Comment: NO there is no error in database or php.. i am not able to get a correct option from my dropdown.. like if i select two.. the output is the string which has all values of dropdown appended by space.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
```

remove "selected" and try

```
 <option>Open this select menu</option>
```

Comment: Without that the output to databse is just "One Two Three". Not the one i select

Comment: give a name to select !

Answer (score 0):

**change your options value**

**give name to select drop down..for example i am giving selectmenu**

**And where you post your data use this name there.**

```
<select class="custom-select" multiple name="selectmenu">
 <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
 <option value="One">One</option>
 <option value="Two">Two</option>
 <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
```